# Debian Bookworm doesn't works with unknow message in boot sequence

Tags: boot, debian

I have an installation of Debian Bookworm in a Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen 4 (Intel Core i7-13 512 GB SSD M2, 32 GB Ram, graphics Intel Irisx) and when I try to boot the only thing that the system shows is this

```
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625895/arch-boot-warning-pci-dpc-rp-pio-log-size-0-is-invalid) says that it is a problem from the kernel but doesn't have a clue about what I can do.

The thing is that the computer is blocked when it shows those two lines.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

PD: I tried to install Debian Trixie but the current installer has problems recognising and reading private drivers from USB storage.

Comment: Are you trying to boot from a live USB? Does it work on any other computers? It might just be a non-working usb (errors while writing or downloading, etc). And tried any boot codes? I can only remember `nomodeset` offhand, I think

Comment: Don't focus on that messages, they're innocuous and not the cause of the GUI not starting.

Comment: I try to boot with a Debial Trixie live and it works well, with all the drivers and stuff working.